# @FacesConverter(forClass = Clazz.class) and p:calendar

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar, converters, jsf-2.2

Basic Joda Time converter (the code is absolutely superfluous for the context of this thread) :

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
@FacesConverter(forClass = DateTime.class)
public class DateTimeConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || value.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa Z").parseDateTime(value).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | UnsupportedOperationException e) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, null, "Message"), e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (value == null) {
            return "";
        }

        if (!(value instanceof DateTime)) {
            throw new ConverterException("Error");
        }

        try {
            return DateTimeFormat.forPattern("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa Z").print(((DateTime) value).withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("zoneId")));
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new ConverterException("Error", e); // Not required.
        }
    }
}
```

Why does it not work with a `<p:calendar>` unless/until it is explicitly specified by using the `converter` attribute?

```
<p:calendar converter="#{dateTimeConverter}" value="{bean.dateTimeValue}" .../>
```

Like other components, it is expected to work without mentioning the `converter` attribute because the converter is decorated with

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = DateTime.class)
```

Is this feature not supported by `<p:calendar>`?

Using PrimeFaces 5.2 and JSF 2.2.12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on 5.2's [`CalendarRenderer#encodeEnd()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2.RC3/org/primefaces/component/calendar/CalendarRenderer.java#58), it uses [`CalendarUtils#getValueAsString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/5.2.RC3/org/primefaces/component/calendar/CalendarUtils.java#41) to obtain the value for output. It indeed doesn't consult via [`Application#createConverter(Class)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#createConverter-java.lang.Class-) if there's a converter by class.

```
51          //first ask the converter
52          if(calendar.getConverter() != null) {
53              return calendar.getConverter().getAsString(context, calendar, value);
54          }
55          //Use built-in converter
56          else {
57              SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(calendar.calculatePattern(), calendar.calculateLocale(context));
58              dateFormat.setTimeZone(calendar.calculateTimeZone());
59              
60              return dateFormat.format(value);
61          }
```

That confirms the behavior you observed. You'd best create an issue report to PrimeFaces guys which requests adding an `instanceof Date` check in place, and in the opposite case obtain the converter by class from the application something like below:

```
Converter converter = context.getApplication().createConverter(value.getClass());
if (converter != null) {
    return converter.getAsString(context, calendar, value);
}
else {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(value.getClass());
}
```

This would indeed make sense given the increasing use of Java8's `java.time` API. There are by the way a few other places in `CalendarRenderer` and `CalendarUtils` where this could/should be implemented (and where they are actually performing an `instanceof` check, but not delegating it to the converter by class, if any).

Comment: :D I was just going to answer: did you check the source…  wondering why people don't do that. The source is open, for more than one reason

Comment: @Kukeltje : Not in this particular case I knew the answer before but I would usually insist upon asking questions affecting the internal framework functionality even though I were to know the answer beforehand. I personally believe opinions from different people are essential. I do not take this kind of things lightly. (BTW, It dates back to a long time ago. I observed this behaviour a long back but I simply ignored it because mentioning a single `converter` attribute with a `<p:calendar>` was not a pain in fingers :) ).

Comment: @Tiny: (not a rant, just a comment ;-) Ok, but If you kind of knew the answer beforehand, than why not state so and ask a question like: 'Is there a specific reason why the behaviour and implementation is such and so'. You'll still get different opinions, maybe even more so, because in this case I would have answered "I see not reason this behaviour is normal, I assume a bug/omission'. Compare that to my 'comment' above... For me (and I know you are not one of them) people seem to be 'lazy' if they ask questions that can be found by 'simply' analysing the open source code. Cheers...

Comment: I have created an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/579).